# OpenCL/OpenGL interoperability texture segfault

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm trying to use OpenCL with OpenGL interop. to compute pathtracing algorithm on GPU and then draw GL texture to quad. Works as intended on Intel CPU but when I try to run in on GTX 970 there's segfault on unlocking that GL texture. Dunno if that's the cause or the running kernel. I'll let the code speak for itself. I'm using OpenCL C++ wrapper btw.

GL texture creation

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, framebuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); //Unbind texture
```

CL texture allocation

```
m_textureCL = cl::ImageGL(m_context,
        CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        texture,
        &errCode);
```

RunKernel function

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Lock texture
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::vector<cl::Memory> glObjects; //Create vector of GL objects to lock
glObjects.push_back(m_textureCL); //Add created CL texture buffer
glFlush(); //Flush GL queue

errCode = m_cmdQueue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&glObjects, NULL, NULL);
if(errCode != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "Error locking texture" << errCode << std::endl;
    return errCode;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Run queue
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
errCode = m_cmdQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
        m_kernel,
        cl::NullRange,
        cl::NDRange(height*width),
        cl::NullRange,
        NULL,
        NULL);
if(errCode != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "Error running queue: " << errCode << std::endl;
    return errCode;
}
//---------------------------------------


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Unlock
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
errCode = m_cmdQueue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&glObjects, NULL, NULL);
if(errCode != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "Error unlocking texture: " << errCode << std::endl;
    return errCode;
} <<------ Here's where segfault occurs, can't get past this point
```

Kernel function def.

```
__kernel void RadianceGPU (
    __write_only image2d_t texture,
    other_stuff...)
```

Writing to texture in kernel

```
write_imagef(
        texture,
        (int2)(x, height-y-1),
        (float4)(
            clamp(framebuffer[id].x, 0.0f, 1.0f),
            clamp(framebuffer[id].y, 0.0f, 1.0f),
            clamp(framebuffer[id].z, 0.0f, 1.0f),
            1.0f) * 1.0f);
```

Interesting is that write_imagef() works despite the texture being UNSIGNED_BYTE.

EDIT:
So I finally figured out what caused the problem. It was setting wrong display while creating CL properties. I just pasted there window from GLFW, which causes problem on Nvidia drivers. You need to use glxGetCurrentDisplay or glfwGetX11Display. This fixes the segfault.

Comment: Which version of OpenCL are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the exact same problem as you, passing the incorrect display parameter to the cl context constructor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m not sure this is your problem but I´ll give it a shot anyway.

You have not synchronized access to glObjects in a portable way. From OpenCL 1.1:

> Prior to calling clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects, the application must
>   ensure that any pending GL operations which access the objects
>   specified in mem_objects have completed. This may be accomplished
>   portably by issuing and waiting for completion of a glFinish command
>   on all GL contexts with pending references to these objects.
>   Implementations may offer more efficient synchronization methods; for
>   example on some platforms calling glFlush may be sufficient, or 
>   synchronization may be implicit within a thread, or there may be
>   vendor
>   - specific extensions that enable placing a fence in the GL command stream and waiting for completion of that fence in the CL command
>   queue. Note that no synchronization methods other than glFinish are
>   portable between OpenGL implementations at this time.

Basically glFinish is required for portable behavior.

In the paragraph below the already quoted there is more info that might be of interest:

> Similarly, after calling clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects, the application 
>   is responsible for ensuring that any pending OpenCL operations
>   which access the objects specified in mem_objects have completed
>   prior to executing subsequent GL commands which reference these
>   objects. This may be accomplished portably by calling 
>   clWaitForEvents with the event object returned by clEnqueueRelease GL
>   Objects, or by calling clFinish. As above, some implementations
>   may offer more efficient methods.

Here is a link to the document quoted from: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf#nameddest=section-9.8.6

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a shot once I get the chance. Another thing that bothers me is when I allocate CL texture I cannot access the GL texture. This happens when I am using Nvidia opencl 1.2 and OpenGL 4.5 but there's no trouble whatsoever when using opencl 1.2 from AMD on Intel CPU/GPU and OpenGL 3.3

Comment: @Nixx Post that as a another question code and all.

Answer (score 0):

As OP already explained in their edit, the problem was invalid value for the `CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR` property, that is passed into `cl::Context`'s constructor:

```cpp
cl_context_properties cps[] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) gl_context,
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentDisplay(), <-- make sure that you aren't passing SDL_Window*, for example
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) (platforms[0])(),
    0
};
```

After this the properties are used as usual with the constructor:

```
cl::Context context{CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cps, nullptr, nullptr, &result};
```

The root cause for this problem is that while there is an abundance of resources in the internet on how to create an OpenCL-OpenGL interop context, almost all of them only cover how to do it on Windows. For an X11 system, the information is quite scarce and needs to be pieced together from various sources.